# gerund and infinitive differences

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

> 1)Nobody likes being  cheated
>
> 2)Nobody likes to be cheated

Are both sentences correct? If yes, what is the difference in meaning of the two sentences?

Comment: Both sentences are fine and have the same meaning.